# Use same settings for two different locations on nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, location

I have the following configs at my nginx.conf:

```
   location /records/load.js {
        proxy_next_upstream off;

        proxy_pass http://scala-front;
        break;
    }

   location /features/download.csv {
        proxy_next_upstream off;

        proxy_pass http://scala-front;
        break;
    }
```

As you can see, the both locations share the same settings. Is there anyway to configure multiple locations for the same settings so I would have just one block? (I've tried some regex so far but can't figure out how to work with slashes locations containing slashes).

Thanks

Comment: Put into file and use `include`. BTW, you don't need `break` here

Comment: @AlexeyTen what I actually would like to do is something like: `location (/records/load.js|/features/download.csv) {` ...

Comment: It's a bad idea. Though you could use regexp in location. See docs

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the docs. Could give me more details on why you think it's a bad ideia? Performance/Security reasons?

Comment: They are processed differently. It could give some unexpected surprises. They are slower.